# Issues with accessing HTTP resources with Embedded Orbeon

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, orbeon, xforms

I'm currently running into issues with accessing HTTP resources (which are all local) while using the XForms Filter for Orbeon (in accordance with  http://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/filter.html).

I am using a Java Servlet to process the data, and I'm trying to use the xf:submission element to access the Servlet in order to get/post the data required. The Java App and Orbeon wars are both deployed in the same tomcat instance, with all of the session handling etc set up as described in the link above.

Iniitally, the Servlet forwards the request to a .JSP with the XForms implementation, which loads fine. However, the page is then meant to request the data and display it. However, it doesnt do this - and the tomcat localhost access logs show no requests were made.

I know both the java code (and the XForms implementation) is correct, as I have written two .JSP's containing the java code from the servlet (and then call the JSP's directly from the xf:submission instead of the HTTP requests) and it works perfectly.

```
                    <xf:submission id="post-results-submission"
                       ref="instance('categories-instance')"
                       resource="http://localhost:8082/EmbeddedTesting/questionnaire"
                       method="post"
                       serialization="application/xml"
                       mediatype="application/xml"
                       replace=""/>

                    <xf:submission id="get-data-submission"
                       ref="instance('response-instance')"
                       resource="http://localhost:8082/EmbeddedTesting/questionnaire"
                       method="post"
                       serialization="application/xml"
                       mediatype="application/xml"
                       replace="instance"
                       instance="categories-instance"/>
```

These are the submission elements for accessing the HTTP resources.

Is there a reason these aren't being called at all? (as shown by logs) and if so, is it possible to fix them?

Also to note - I tested the servlet itself using the Advanced REST Chrome app and through the orbeon form builder HTTP actions (then clicking test) and both worked fine. It just wont work here for some reason. I've also made sure that the licence (for Orbeon Forms PE) is in the WEB-INF/resources/config and that it is still valid.

Here is a link to my XForms, uploaded to dropbox as an XML file so it can be previewed on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/aq4zx39ohjulcbx/index.xml?dl=0

I'm not sure if this is something I can actually do outside of Form Runner/Builder, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That `replace=""` on one of your submissions looks incorrect. Could you fix this (and set to it to `instance` or `all`, whatever you meant), and see if that fixes the problem by any chance?

Comment: If not, what is the problem? You're loading a page, at what URL? What are you doing on that page as a user? What does that trigger in the code? What is the "not working" symptom you're observing? What is supposed to happen instead?

Comment: My apologies for not explaining that. The idea is the get-data-submission is called when XForms is loaded, which will pull the XML data from my Java Application. When the user submits the data, post-results-submission is called to POST the data to the source, so it can pass it on to the Java Application for further processing. But the submissions dont seem to work when using HTTP links - rather than the JSP pages I used to test, the tomcat logs show no evidence of XForms accessing the URL and POSTing the data, and I cant understand why.

Comment: Robbie, so you're saying that this initial data loading works in one case and not in another. It doesn't work when you have a `resource="http://localhost:8082/EmbeddedTesting/questionnaire`, but it works when you have a link to a JSP, like `resource="/questionnaire.jsp`; is this what you're seeing? Also, you are accessing the XForms page that calls the service using a URL pointing to "your web app", not the Orbeon Forms web app, correct? -Alex

Comment: Yes, that's all correct. I cant work out why the HTTP request doesn't work through the xf:submission component. I tried putting the HTTP link into Form Builder HTTP Service to use the test function and it worked perfectly, despite the fact the code Form Builder generated is almost identical to mine (minus the class="fr-service" attribute). For reference, here is what Form Builder generated in the test -

Comment: `<xf:submission id="HTTP-GET-submission" class="fr-service"
                           ref="instance('fr-service-request-instance')"                           resource="http://localhost.8082/EmbeddedTesting/questionnaire"
                           method="post"
                           serialization="application/xml"
                           mediatype="application/xml"
                           replace="instance"
                           instance="fr-service-response-instance"/>`

Comment: OK, can you reproduce this with a super-simple form that uses an `<xf:submission>` to do a GET on https://httpbin.org/xml, and, say, shows the value inside `/slideshow/slide[1]/title` with an `<xf:input>`? If you can reproduce this, can you put the source for that "JSP" in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/), share the URL with us here, so I can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Here is the source for what you asked for https://gist.github.com/iiAnderson/6cc1d1925b3489e8143bcf7a433e7288. It all worked perfectly with no problems! Do you think theres a possibility it's due to the fact the servlet im trying to access from XForms is hosted locally? All of the external data sources I have tried now seem to work. I'm all out of ideas as to why else it wont acces it! Thanks, Robbie.

Comment: So I have no clue how, but it now works fine. I ended up splitting the Tomcat Instance into two, so Orbeon Embedded is running on one instance, and the servlet on the other. I'll look further into it tomorrow. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: In the end the issue was that the HTTP requests weren't being called (I think) because the address was in the same project within tomcat. Once I moved the XForms fillter into a different container and accessed through a different resource address it worked!

Comment: Robbie, I'm not sure why things wouldn't work if in the same container, but I'm glad you found a solution to this one. And thanks for sharing what worked for you.